# Calculate Length of Time It Takes a car to lose speed from different starting speeds

Tags: calculus

Hello can someone help me out with the function to calculate the speed drop for an interval of time just based on wind drag for a car. (assume there is no other frictional forces acting just wind drag)  The problem I am running into is that the rate of deceleration is changing the instant the speed changes (lower wind speed, lower wind force on the car).  The instant the speed lowers the rate of deceleration follows instantly.  How is it possible to calculate what the speed of the car would be in X amount of time after putting the car in neutral?  I am doing this for a project to show how aerodynamics affect how fast a car will slow down.

Answer (score 1):

Force exerted by a fluid on an object is directly proportional to its instantaneous velocity.

$$F\,{\propto}\,v$$
$$F=-kv$$
$$ma=-kv$$
$${\int}m{dv\over dt}={\int}-k{dx\over dt}$$
$$mv=-kx$$
$$m{dx\over dt}=-kx$$
$${\int}m{dx\over x}={\int}-kdt$$
$${\log}x={-kx\over m}$$
$$x=e^{-kx\over m}$$
$${dx\over dt}={{e^{-kx\over m}}\over dt}$$
$$v={-k\over m}e^{-kx\over m}$$